# Adding icons next to categories in wp_nav_menu

Tags: plugins, menus, dropdown

Is there a way to add a category icon next to a menu item?

I'm using the [Category Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-thumbnails/) plugin to allow each catagory to have their own icon. However I'm struggling to incorperate this into my `wp_nav_menu();`.

I've customized my menu to look how I'd like it to:

[image]

Would I have to create a custom one from scratch or is there a way to piggyback onto the default one?

Comment: I've used this handy easy method, although I suppose having dropdowns may require additional CSS changes. https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-image/ Beyond that, probably some Walker filtering fun.  :)

Comment: You can implement it using `:before` selector in CSS